# Adding xml element in xml file dynamically which should reflect in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

I want to add xml element with text in a xml file at run time(XML file is
    attachted at the last also its path in the package).What my code going to do is

1. Taking input from edittext when somebutton is pressed
2. that input text should be add as the element(Item Tag) to the xml file
       (pnrstored.xml file whose directory is packagename/res/Vlaues/pnrstored.xml)
3. pnrstored.xml is used in the adapter(actually string array define in it)
4. this adpater is attacted to the listview
5. listview should display all recently added value at first as well as previous value
   Only displaying necessory code.

My problem ..is following code is changing the pnrstored file..if there is some error in directory when i initilaize StreamResult result plz check that first..

```
 public class Pnr extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        ListView lvSavedPNR;
         EditText etPNR;

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pnrSaved, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            lvSavedPNR.setAdapter(adapter);
                somebutton.onclicklisner;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String  pnr = etPNR.getEditableText().toString();

                        savePNR(pnr);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        private void savePNR(String pnr2) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = documentBuilder.parse("pnrstored.xml");
                Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

                // Root Element
                Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();

                Collection<Item> svr = new ArrayList<Item>();
                svr.add(new Item(pnr));

                for (Item i : svr) {
                    // server elements
                    Element item = document.createElement("Item");
                    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.getName()));
                    rootElement.appendChild(item);
                    root.appendChild(rootElement);

                }

                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult  ( "pnrstored.xml");
                transformer.transform(source, result);
            }
        public static class Item {
            String PNR;
            Item(String x){PNR=x;}
            public String getName() { return PNR; }

        }
```

packagename/res/Vlaues/pnrstored.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name="pnrSaved">
            <item>1234567890</item>

        </string-array>
    </resources>
```